# Case insensitive duplicates SQL

Tags: sql, mysql, postgresql, duplicate-data

So I have a users table where the user.username has many duplicates like:

`username` and `Username` and `useRnAme`
`john` and `John` and `jOhn`

That was a bug and these three records should have been only one.

I'm trying to come up with a SQL query that lists all of these cases ordered by their creation date, so ideally the result should be something like this:

```
username jan01
useRnAme jan02
Username jan03
john     feb01 
John     feb02
jOhn     feb03
```

Any suggestions will be much appreciated

Comment: @hdx: Your question is tagged `mysql` and `postgresql`. Are you using both?

Comment: @hdx: Are you actually storing the dates in that format and not in a date column?

Comment: @Peter Lang, in fact any sql like language would do, I can port it. I'm using postgresql.

Comment: @Mark Byers it is in date format that was just a basic example

Comment: @hdx: It might be better to make different queries for each database. Trying to write queries that work in all databases is usually a bad idea.

Comment: Thx guys I really freaking love this site :P

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Leaving aside the issue of case sensitivity for a moment, the basic strategy is:

```
 SELECT username, create_date FROM your_table
     WHERE username IN 
     (SELECT username FROM your_table GROUP BY username HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
 ORDER BY username, create_date
```

Many RDBMSes (including MySQL assuming that you are using CHAR or VARCHAR for the username column), perform case-insensitive searching by default.  For those databases, the above solution will work.  To solve the case sensitivity issue for other products , wrap all except the first occurrence of username in the uppercase conversion function specific to your RDBMS:

```
 SELECT username, create_date FROM your_table
     WHERE UPPER(username) IN 
     (SELECT UPPER(username) FROM your_table GROUP BY UPPER(username) HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
 ORDER BY username, create_date
```

Comment: If it's for MYSQL the UPPER is not needed and might even make the query unnecessarily slow.

Comment: Yes, that's true (and true for various other RDBMSes as well).  I'll modify the answer to reflect that.

Comment: is there a way to make sure the dates are in ascending order for each group of dups?

Comment: Did you include the ORDER BY clause, with the columns appropriately changed for your database?

Comment: Ok so I found the problem... we need to have "UPPER(username), create_date" at very the end. Thx for the help!

Comment: Not sure I understand why that's so, but I'm glad you found the solution.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like these

```
SELECT UserName, CreatedDate
FROM User
WHERE LOWER(TRIM(UserName)) IN 
(
SELECT LOWER(TRIM(UserName))
FROM User
GROUP BY LOWER(TRIM(UserName))
HAVING count(*) > 1
)
```

Comment: Opps, I see Larry posted the same thing first

Answer (score 0):

Use ToLower() or equivalent function in your SELECT, and order by that column.

Comment: That will include usernames that do not suffer from the multi-entry problem.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, a case-sensitive compare is done using a binary collation.  So you could join the table on itself, looking for rows where the case sensitive compare is different from the case insensitive compare:

```
select *
from YourTable t1
inner join YourTable t2 
on t1.name <> t2.name collate latin1_bin
and t1.name = t2.name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT UserName, CreatedDate
FROM YourTable 
WHERE UserName COLLATE UTF8_BIN != LOWER(UserName COLLATE UTF8_BIN)
GROUP BY UserName, CreatedDate
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: **From review queue**: May I request you to please add some context around your source-code. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Answer (score 0):

so this is what i came up with. this was written against a postgres db but should work fine still against other sql engine.

```
select * from user u join user u2
on upper(u.email)=upper(u2.email) where u.id != u2.id
order by u.email;
```

so the query assume that the email are duplicate but the ids are not so it is looking to pull records with a duplicate email (case insensitive) but with unique id